# Has anyone got Ripple's inbuilt Remote Web Inspector working?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks, ripple

I have  Blackberry webworks apps, and I'm using the Ripple Chrome extension (Ripple UI (v0.9.12)).

I'm testing my app in a BB emulator at the moment, and am manually running WEIRNE (remote web inspector).

I'd much prefer to use the inbuilt ripple version (as WEIRNE is ridiculously unstable).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are these BlackBerry 10 webworks apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can also build your app with Web Inspector enabled, then access

```
http://deviceip:1337/
```

in your desktop browser when the app is running in the simulator or on the actual device. I use this frequently to monitor ajax calls in the Network tab.

Comment: This is what I've tried to do, but it doesn't work. I've installed WEIRNE separately and manually added the call in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome web inspector in Ripple just like you can any web page with chrome. 
You can right click on an element and click 'Inspect Element'.

If you want manually execute commands in the 'Console' you need to change which frame you are accessing, at the bottom of the 'Console' change 'Top Frame' to document(your filename).

Comment: Not what I wanted - you can do that using ripple, but not when your app is on a device or emulator.

I ended up updating my standalone weirne to the node.js version - seems more stable.